# how following .tpl file works to show table

Tags: php, e-commerce, smarty

Following is a code given in  [book](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=FTZxXyXrFtUC&lpg=PA100&ots=UJmwl4z8fc&dq=smarty%20function%20load%20parameter%20object&pg=PA158#v=onepage&q=smarty%20function%20load%20parameter%20object&f=true)

```
    {* products_list.tpl *}
    {load_presentation_object filename="products_list" assign="obj"}

      {if $obj->mProducts}
      <table class="product-list" border="0">
      <tbody>
      {section name=k loop=$obj->mProducts}
      {if $smarty.section.k.index % 2 == 0}
      <tr>
      {/if}
    <td valign="top">
    <h3 class="product-title">
    <a href="{$obj->mProducts[k].link_to_product}">
    {$obj->mProducts[k].name}
    </a>
    </h3>
    <p>
    {if $obj->mProducts[k].thumbnail neq ""}
    <a href="{$obj->mProducts[k].link_to_product}">
    <img src="{$obj->mProducts[k].thumbnail}"
    alt="{$obj->mProducts[k].name}" />
    </a>
    {/if}
    {$obj->mProducts[k].description}
    </p>

    <p class="section">
    Price:
    {if $obj->mProducts[k].discounted_price != 0}
    <span class="old-price">{$obj->mProducts[k].price}</span>
    <span class="price">{$obj->mProducts[k].discounted_price}</span>
    {else}
    <span class="price">{$obj->mProducts[k].price}</span>
    {/if}
    </p>
    </td>
    {if $smarty.section.k.index % 2 != 0 && !$smarty.section.k.first ||
    $smarty.section.k.last}
    </tr>
    {/if}
    {/section}
    </tbody>
    </table>
    {/if}
```

I am not clear with following line

```
  {if $smarty.section.k.index % 2 == 0}
```

why is the above statement written to see if index is an even number or odd number what effect does this have on table displayed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's creating new table row every two array items.

```
 //open
 {if $smarty.section.k.index % 2 == 0}
   <tr>
 {/if}

 //close
 {if $smarty.section.k.index % 2 != 0 && !$smarty.section.k.first ||
     $smarty.section.k.last}
     </tr>
 {/if}
```

Take a look at this example:

```
 echo "<table border='1'>\n";

 for($i = 0; $i<=10; $i++) {

   if ($i % 2 == 0) {
       echo "<tr>\n";
   }

   echo "<td> ". $i. "contents </td> \n"; 

   if ($i % 2 != 0) {
       echo "</tr> \n";
   }

}

 echo "<table />\n";
```

Comment: then what  does `{if $smarty.section.k.index % 2 != 0 && !$smarty.section.k.first ||
    $smarty.section.k.last}` line do there it is ending before {/tr}

Comment: I get following output a horizontal line `0contents1contents2contents3contents4contents5contents6contents7contents8contents9contents10contents`

Comment: it's an example, look at the source produced by script, i want you understand how this works, an why it is so. not providing full solution.

Comment: Ok I think I have understood here is what I understood when i=0 then it goes in first if loop echo 0.contents and since 0%2==0 so skips second if loop now i=1 so if it skips if(1%2==0)  and prints 1.contents and now checks 1%2!=0 it goes inside the if loop like this it continues , this is fine if I understood clear , why is a newline not coming in your example when a </tr> is happening I executed the code but all come in same row

Comment: It come to same row because i was not providing full html structure, for simplification purposes, checking it now.